# Distributions not being delivered

Tags: google-fabric

I’m facing problems delivering iOS builds of my app to testers.
Many testers are not receiving the invitation and those who does, after some time stop receiving new builds.

In the dashboard I can see them as “invited”. However, they say they didn’t receive any email with the invitation. They also checked spam box and nothing.

Another tester did receive the invitation and started testing. However, he is not receiving new builds.

I have already tried to go to Tools > Beta > selected the tester who did not receive the invitation and deleted it. Then, I added him again, it shows like "invited", but he didn't receive any invitation.

I use Fabric with many other apps and this is the first time I'm having this issue.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Hi, Paul from Fabric here. Sorry you're running into this problem. Could you reach out to us at support@fabric.io with your bundle ID and organization name? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Paul, I've already done that earlier today.

Comment: thanks, I'll follow up with you there.